# Accepting liability to employer contractor

Tags: united-kingdom, negotiation

I work in Finance, and in the course of my employment need to use the services of a 3rd party, who have an existing contract with my employer. Some routine paperwork I would fill to register with the 3rd party asserts that based on the existing contract, I would have *personal* liability for *any* regulatory fees or penalties resulting from my actions. No further detail is offered. Is this reasonable? Country is UK.

My employer wants me to sign the paperwork and is now mildly pushing for this to happen, after my repeated concerns. I'd say we are now up to "mild coercion" issues: other employees signed this without asking questions, surely it's OK, the 3rd party must be reasonable in levying any such penalties, my employer would likely step in if any such issues arise, and anyway, why would I be concerned about penalties if I'm a good actor. 3rd party is a respectable company in their industry, though I'm sure not above passing on penalty fees to clients if they can get away with it.

I think it's shaky legal ground, but aside from this - is this reasonable? Seems majorly not reasonable to me (which I guess shows through my phrasing of the question!), but would be interested in other opinions. It is reasonable for employees to be responsible for their actions, and I'm reasonably senior - in some ways I could be an independent contractor (but am not).

For example, I'd be concerned about cases where the 3rd party has a regulatory, or just plain business requirement to correct my errors, fail to do so, but accepts no responsibility. Or cases where due to errors in other teams within my firm, I interact with the 3rd party leading to penalties, but end up taking the hit.

Comment: I have no idea what the legal situation is in the UK, but in Germany, anything below C-level or owner of the company never has any personal liability. That is insane. Let someone else sign it. Shouldn't be a problem for your boss, right? The one that complained. Surely just another signature in their day full of signatures? I would never sign such a thing. That is a reasonable thing if I'm a majority shareholder, not for Random Joe Fulltime Employee.

Comment: Unfortunately, your problem is somewhere between "legal" and "internal company regulations". About laws, you might get help from https://law.stackexchange.com/, about your company's rules - from your company. I vote to close the question.

Comment: Does the contract state that you are liable for any fees or penalties arising from your *illegal* actions? Illegal actions resulting in penalties would be more understandable.

Comment: @numenor, that doesn't need to go into a contract. You are responsible for illegal actions as far as the law allows.

Comment: *"I would have *personal* liability for any regulatory fees or penalties resulting from my actions."* You cannot have **personal** liability for a **business** matter. When you work as an employee at your company, you represent your company. You are not you, you are just a cog in the machine called "the company". Best advice: if they insist that you have to sign, then you have to insist to quit and find another, more reasonable, job.

Comment: @virolino : "*You cannot have personal liability for a business matter.*" -> in the UK, you ***can***, I'm 99% positive about that. ***BUT*** (basically) you must have failed to respect the law *on purpose*. (see a related [article](https://jebaring.co.uk/commercial-law-firm-in-central-london/risks-and-possible-liabilities-for-directors/) about directors or another one about [employees/contractors](https://www.partnerslaw.co.uk/news/when-can-an-employee-or-a-self-employed-individual-be-personally-liable-for-financial-losses-resulting-from-their-act-or-omission))

Comment: Sanity check: are _you_ a contractor, or an employee? A contractor is a separate business, and of course has to assume liability for their own work -- which is why contractors carry business insurance.

Comment: @OldPadawan: *"failed to respect the law on purpose"* - failing the law on purpose is not a business matter any more, it is a matter of the criminal code.

Comment: @virolino It really depends. The employee may be liable to pay damages due to their illegal behaviour, while also being criminally prosecuted at the same time by the state.

Comment: @virolino But I think OldPadawan misses the mark slightly. I think even if you are only wilfully negligent, you may be liable. Which doesn't require you to act illegally.

Answer (score 7):

This might very be illegal (law.stackexchange.com is better for that question) but a flat out refusal creates a stale mate and nothing can move. Here is one suggestions how to potentially unstuck it.

Ask your company to provide you a letter of indemnification that states that they will assume all of your personal liability related to you signing the contract (maybe unless it's caused by gross negligence or intentional malice).

If this is really completely harmless as the company claims, they should have no problem providing that letter, especially since you are entering this contract at their request to their benefit.

If they refuse, they are being a lot less reasonable than you are which gives you a much stronger negotiation position. It changes your argument to "you want me to do assume a legal risk that you don't want to assume yourself" and invalidates their argument "this is completely harmless, no big deal, everyone does it".

Comment: Yes, a letter of indemnification, and/or extra insurance paid for by the employer.

Comment: Professional indemnity insurance would appear to be the best fit - this is insurance that I, as a UK based contractor, must have as a standard.